# How to add item at top/first?

Tags: tom-select

I tried

```js
select.tomselect.addOption({value: '-1', text: 'All', '$score': 99999 })
```

but that does not work. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tell Tom Select how to sort: https://tom-select.js.org/docs/#sortfield

Also, I don't think supplying a $score field will work since it's already being used and will likely be overwritten by Tom Select. You could supply something else though, say `$custom_sort` and define your sortField parameter to `sortField:[{field:'$custom_sort'},{field:'$score'}]`